# HSV colorspace conversion between opencv vs skimage

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, hsv, color-space

I was comparing the difference between skImage HSV color space and OpenCV hsv colourspace conversion methods, I found the below difference which I didn't understand:

```
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = PIL.Image.open("112.jpg")
data = np.asarray(image)                      #Feeding the same  RGB array
y1=cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(data),cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
y1 = y1.astype(np.uint8)
y2= color.rgb2hsv(data)                       #skimage conversion
```

I used PIL to make sure I am feeding RGB array. Here, when I printed the images I got the following outputs.

```
y1

>>> array([[[ 52,   0, 252],
    [ 52,   0, 252],
    [ 52,   0, 252],
    ...,
    [ 59,   0, 186],
    [ 59,   0, 186],
    [ 59,   0, 186]],

   [[ 52,   0, 252],
    [ 52,   0, 252],
    [ 52,   0, 252],
    ...,
    [ 59,   0, 186],
    [ 59,   0, 186],
    [ 59,   0, 186]],

   [[ 52,   0, 252],
    [ 52,   0, 252],
    [ 52,   0, 252],
    ...,
    [ 59,   0, 187],
    [ 59,   0, 187],
    [ 59,   0, 187]],

   ...,


y2

>>> array([[[0.14465409, 0.21031746, 0.98823529],
    [0.14465409, 0.21031746, 0.98823529],
    [0.14465409, 0.21031746, 0.98823529],
    ...,
    [0.16515152, 0.59139785, 0.72941176],
    [0.16515152, 0.59139785, 0.72941176],
    [0.16515152, 0.59139785, 0.72941176]],

   [[0.14465409, 0.21031746, 0.98823529],
    [0.14465409, 0.21031746, 0.98823529],
    [0.14465409, 0.21031746, 0.98823529],
    ...,
    [0.16515152, 0.59139785, 0.72941176],
    [0.16515152, 0.59139785, 0.72941176],
    [0.16515152, 0.59139785, 0.72941176]],

   [[0.14465409, 0.21031746, 0.98823529],
    [0.14465409, 0.21031746, 0.98823529],
    [0.14465409, 0.21031746, 0.98823529],
    ...,
    [0.16515152, 0.58823529, 0.73333333],
    [0.16515152, 0.58823529, 0.73333333],
    [0.16515152, 0.58823529, 0.73333333]],

   ...,
```

1. why are my y1 and y2 arrays different? do skimage and opencv follow different conversion formulas for the same colorspace?
2. Which is the standard and the most followed way to convert an RGB image to HSV image: "cvtColor(....RGB2HSV) -cv2" or "rgbtohsv() -skimage"?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: too many questions in this question. one question per question please. as for the first question, opencv does NOT alter anything. if you give it BGR, you tell it that. if you give it RGB, you tell it that. matplotlib uses "false color" scales to give grayscale values color. they misrepresent what's actually there. further, when you give uint8 data to OpenCV's cvtColor, it will return uint8 data. in the case of hues, the range is 0..179 (360 degrees of hue, resolution of two degrees).

Comment: Exactly as Christoph says. For more comparable results, pass `float` to **OpenCV** with `y1=cv2.cvtColor(data.astype(np.float),cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)`

Comment: Thank you very much christoph, I made the edits and reposted the question. Mark I did make the changes but I am still not close enough to compare both the skiamge and opencv?

Comment: Mark, I also noticed that when I am using np.float32(data), I am losing G channel values? is there a specific reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

When converting to HSV, CV2 and Skimage use different scales. For CV2, HSV values are within the range of 0 and 255, while for skimage HSV values are within the range of 0 and 1. Just multiply the HSV values from skimage and convert them into integer and you will get the same values for both CV2 and SKIMAGE.